# My mouse sometimes right clicks when I try to left click

Tags: mouse

This mouse has been working just fine for months, but this morning it started right clicking sometimes when I try to left click. It's a standard optical mouse with two regular buttons, a scroll wheel/button, and a red LED on the bottom. I can fix it temporarily by prying off the left button and cleaning under it, but then it starts acting up again after a few minutes of use. What could be causing this and how can I fix it? Could this have something to do with the humidity? I recently moved into a basement that is full of humidity in the air.

Comment: There is no permanent fix other than a new mouse.

Comment: @Moab yeah, mice are pretty cheap, might as well buy one if it keeps acting up...

Comment: You could spray the switches in contact cleaner, but as that's about $£€ 8 a can, if it was a cheap mouse, you're fighting diminishing returns.

Comment: As @Tetsujin suggests, use a contact cleaner... but a cheap alternative is liquefied gas "canned air". A *very* short burst of liquid, sprayed with the can held inverted, can dissolve some gunk and expel it. *Use safety glasses or face shield to protect eyes.* Not worth buying a new can, but if you have it already...

Comment: The problem might not be the physical mouse at all; it might be a driver problem. For example, this unresolved description of the problem makes it clear that the problem is not the physical mouse: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/mouse-left-click-sometimes-acts-as-right-click/5418dc52-1cd0-4632-82cb-c0d253f81a51. So, try a different mouse first to see if it has the same problem. If the problem goes away, then the problem is with the first physical mouse. If the problem remains, then it is likely a driver or software problem.

Answer (score 3):

This  works for me but I only found it after much trial and error - in other words I cannot explain the how and why. Go to devices and click on mouse. Then go to the folder  'mouse properties' and then UNCLICK 'automatically move pointer to the default button in dialogue box' Then apply and you will find that the problem disappears - DON'T ASK ME WHY BUT IT DOES.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 11 version:  Settings -> Bluetooth & devices -> Mouse. Related Settings,
click Additional mouse settings -> opens Mouse Properties dialog. In my case, I was having the issue described, but my "automatically move..." checkbox was already off. Change any setting, click Apply, restore setting, Apply. This seems to cure the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The microswitches inside of mine have a finite lifespan, and can begin to act strangely if they are near the point of failure. I have experienced all kinds of problems related this personally, and service my own mice regularly to ensure that they remain in good condition.

The cost of a replacement microswitch is significantly cheaper than replacing the entire mouse. However, the tools and cost of building the necessary experience, or the labor to have someone else do it, is not.

Unless you're looking to pickup electronics repair as a hobby, I would recommend buying yourself a new mouse. And if you like this particular mouse, buy an identical model; this will allow you to verify whether it is a hardware or a software problem.